# What is ??= operator in Swifter project

Tags: ios, swift, operator-keyword

I've seen an operator `??=` which used in source code of [Swifter](https://github.com/mattdonnelly/Swifter/) library in GitHub but no where talking about this operator and what it can do... this operator located under source files in [SwifterFollowers.swift Line 89.](https://github.com/mattdonnelly/Swifter/blob/master/Sources/SwifterFollowers.swift#L89)

Code snippet to this file:

```
func getUserFollowersIDs(for userTag: UserTag,
                         cursor: String? = nil,
                         count: Int? = nil,
                         success: CursorSuccessHandler? = nil,
                         failure: FailureHandler? = nil) {
    let path = "followers/ids.json"

    var parameters = [String: Any]()
    parameters[userTag.key] = userTag.value
    parameters["cursor"] ??= cursor /* --- Here --- */
    parameters["stringify_ids"] = true
    parameters["count"] ??= count

    self.getJSON(path: path, baseURL: .api, parameters: parameters, success: { json, _ in            
        success?(json["ids"], json["previous_cursor_str"].string, json["next_cursor_str"].string)
        }, failure: failure)
}
```

Comment: Just search for the operator in the source: https://github.com/mattdonnelly/Swifter/blob/master/Sources/Operator%2B%2B.swift#L14: “If `rhs` is not `nil`, assign it to `lhs`.”

Comment: This was actually proposed in [Swift evolution](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0024-optional-value-setter.md) once, but it was [rejected](https://lists.swift.org/pipermail/swift-evolution-announce/2016-February/000043.html). It's simply not as useful in Swift, as it is in languages where null-ability is encoded into the type system. `x ??= y` still leaves `x` as `Optional`, requiring unwrapping to access the value, even if `y` was *just* assigned to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that `??=` created by the developer in [Operator++](https://github.com/mattdonnelly/Swifter/blob/master/Sources/Operator%2B%2B.swift) file.

Then this operator only works in `Swifter` project and here is the logic:

```
/// If `rhs` is not `nil`, assign it to `lhs`.
infix operator ??= : AssignmentPrecedence // { associativity right precedence 90 assignment } // matches other assignment operators

/// If `rhs` is not `nil`, assign it to `lhs`.
func ??=<T>(lhs: inout T?, rhs: T?) {
    guard let rhs = rhs else { return }
    lhs = rhs
}
```